# Pure-FPTD-Mysql TLS SFTP : permission denied

Tags: ftp, sftp, pure-ftpd

I've a working FTP service on my server, connected to a MySQL database to manage my users, using pure-ftpd-mysql.

I try to enable the FTP users to use SFTP. The FTP login works fine, but the SFTP login always answer : `Permission denied, please try again.`

My certificate, issued my letsencrypt seem to be working fine (it prompted well on filezilla the first time).

Here is the syslog when I restart the pure-ftpd-mysql service :

```
Aug  3 12:12:02 fidcar-ftp pure-ftpd-mysql[4822]: Starting ftp server: Running: /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd-mysql -l mysql:/etc/pure-ftpd/db/mysql.conf -E -p 30000:50000 -8 UTF-8 -j -P 212.47.231.168 -Y 1 -O clf:/var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log -u 2000 -J HIGH -A -B
```

As you can see, the -Y option is defined to 1, so the TLS seems to be activated.

On my var/log/auth logs, i can find those lines :

```
Aug  3 12:35:14 fidcar-ftp sshd[5006]: Failed password for invalid user <mysftpuser> from <myip> port 51776 ssh2
Aug  3 12:35:14 fidcar-ftp sshd[5006]: Connection closed by invalid user <mysftpuser> <myip> port 51776 [preauth]
```

Is Pure-FTPD is supposed to find the user and allow the connexion ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

SFTP is SSH-based. It is not related in any way to PureFTPd. You can also see on the log lines that they’re coming from `sshd`.

If you want encrypted FTP, you need to use *FTPS*. Depending on your configuration you’ll need to set up the FTP client to use either FTP Implicit SSL/TLS (different port) or FTP Explicit SSL/TLS (same port, uses `STARTTLS` command).

Be aware that encrypted FTP still uses multiple connections, but firewall helpers can no longer extract this information from the now-encrypted control connection. You may not be able to use encrypted FTP from behind restrictive firewalls.